# Merge CSV Files Error 1004

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, csv

So I am trying to make a macro that will merge multiple .csv files into one excel worksheet. I used the following tutorial for it:
[vba code](https://learndataanalysis.org/merge-multiple-csv-files-in-excel-with-vba/)

However, once I put in the correct path to the .csv files, I get "Run-time error '1004: Sorryy we couldn't find April2019.csv. Is it possible it was moved, renamed or deleted?" (April2019.csv is the first file in the folder).
So the macro obviously finds the right folder and the .csv file but then it stops and I have no idea why. I've been trying to change the code around a bit but it won't work. The code below is what I am using at the moment, credits to Jie Jenn who made the tutorial.

```
Option Explicit

Dim wsMerge As Worksheet
Dim RowInsert As Long

Sub Merge_Files()
Const FolderPath As String = "H:\Documents\Invoices\"

Dim Files As String
Dim wbTemp As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long

Set wsMerge = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Merge")

RowInsert = 2

Files = Dir(FolderPath + "*.csv")

Do Until Files = ""
        
        Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Files)
        
        With wbTemp.Worksheets(1)
        LastRow = .Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        
                .Range("A2:N" & LastRow).Copy
                wsMerge.Range("A" & RowInsert).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                
                Application.DisplayAlerts = False
                wbTemp.Close False
                Application.DisplayAlerts = True
                
                RowInsert = RowInsert + LastRow - 1
        End With
        
        Files = Dir()
Loop

MsgBox "File Merge Complete", vbInformation

End Sub
```

The error arrises when I "Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Files)"

I hope this is enough context for the problem.

Comment: [Debugging VBA Code • My Online Training Hub](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/debugging-vba-code)

Comment: [Excel Macros - Debugging a Code - Tutorialspoint](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/excel_macros/excel_macros_debugging_code.htm)

Comment: I have already tried debugging the code but I can't figure out how to fix the problem. That is the reason why I made a post about it.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are only giving the filename when using this part of code `Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Files)`. Files only contains the filename for example `myfile.csv`. The path is missing. Modify it to become:

```
 Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & Files)
```